# force latex to put a two column figure in a two column paper in the desired place

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column

I am writing my first article (two column Springer template), let say that in a certain page, in the middle of the first column I want to insert a "two column figure" and continue the writing from the begin of the second column. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: If I recollect correctly, LaTeX *never* places a float that spans two column at the bottom of pages.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: If I remember correctly, `figure*` is always at the top of the page in a `two-column` layout

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes, only `t` and `p` are allowed as position specifiers for “double-column” floats: Lamport’s book states this explicitly on p. 197.  To the OP: although it is possible to get what you ask for by playing some (very) nasty trick, you should consider that whenever you have to coerce LaTeX in this way, you are almost surely breaking a long-established typographic rule.  I think this is exactly the case: as far as I know, two-column figures at the bottom of pages are traditionally shunned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stfloats` package (from the `sttools` bundle) allows placement of page-wide figure at the bottom of the page with this code:

```
  \begin{figure*}[b]
    ..........
   \end{figure*}
```

Comment: @ Bernard: Thank you, this what I am looking for.

Comment: @user137684: Besides accepting the answer, consider upvoting it too.  (I know for sure that unique upvote that has been casted until now is not yours… ;-)